# What's the best way to check if the browser supports html5 using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, flash, html

I want to use a fallback solution for HTML5 / flash audio players.

I wonder if I can use jQuery to check if HTML5 is supported.

I know there is .support() ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/ ) but I'm not sure which would be a bullet proof check.

Comment: Just a small note: you shouldn't check for HTML5 support, but for support of specific HTML5 features. However, I'm not really sure what the best method is, so I guess I'll leave that up to another to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for HTML5 features using Modernizr.

http://www.modernizr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/). From documentation:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = Modernizr.audio.ogg ? 'background.ogg' :
            Modernizr.audio.mp3 ? 'background.mp3' :
                                  'background.m4a';
audio.play();
```

EDIT: Now that the question has changed, [this](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) might be more in line with what you need.

Comment: I don't want to build the HTML5 player. I want to embed existing player widgets. Let's assume vimeo players: If browser supports HTML5 show the HTML5 player widget, else Flash.

Comment: You said audio players, I found an audio example. If you wanted a video player (AFAIK, Vimeo doesn't have a pure audio one yet), why wouldn't you say so in the question? Anyway, I edited the answer.

Comment: Oh my god. It doesn't really matter if it's audio or video... I just want to check if HTML5 is supported. But thanks for trying.

Comment: @Martin HTML5 is a huge group of feature and browser only support a portion of them. If you want to use HTML5 video/audio, I suggest you to further check the browser support state and check the use of Modernizr - most feature checking is using browser specific code which is not provided by jQuery.

Comment: Ok, found Modernizr mentioned a couple of times on research. Will check if it's worth embedding a 7KB script. No fallback pushes HTML5 tho :) Thanks!